# Ionic app in Release mode shows white screen

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I try to run my Ionic 4 app in release mode (both in Simulator and a local iOS device) the splash screen comes up and then all I get is a white screen.

For example, when I execute this command:

`ionic cordova run ios --release --prod -- --verbose`

I also tried a brand new 'myApp' project (https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cli) and exactly the same thing happens. There is no error even when I add verbose and consolelogs.

In debug mode, a local server is started and that renders the app. How is it supposed to work in release mode?

Update: I installed the browser platform since I can't inspect an iOS device in Chrome and I see this error in the browser console which I'll now investigate:

`Error: Cannot find module '@angular/core'`

Comment: try doing this `npm i @angular/core` and try running again

Comment: @MohanGopi thx but that didn't help. same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue was that I somehow referenced some things from 'ionic-angular' instead of '@ionic/angular'. I don't know how that happened or why it didn't cause issues in Debug mode.

There was also a node-sass issue that I had to resolve first. Once I did that, I got some helpful errors running `npm test`.

```
rm -rf node_modules 
sudo rm -rf /tmp/* 
rm -rf /root/.npm/node-sass 
npm uninstall --save node-sass 
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```